# Case statement with one or more values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following matrix, made up of several variables

```
| A | B | C |
-------------
| X | X |   |
| X |   |   |
|   | X | X |
|   | X |   |
-------------
```

I'm trying to write a case expression that selects individual columns but also identifies when one or more columns are populated with a different value

Example

```
case 
   when ColA = 'X' and ColB IS NULL and ColC IS NULL then 'Good'
   when ColA IS NULL and ColB = 'X' and ColC IS NULL then 'Bad'
   etc
end
```

But what do I write in SQL if I want to check for two or more columns (A,B,or C) having X's with the rest of the fields being null? This would be for any combination of 2 or more columns having an X without spelling out every possible combination in a case statement (my actual data has 8 columns with 2 or more possibly having values in them). Not sure if it's a nested case expresssion or something more foreign that's closer to an If/Then Loop.

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result. (Also, those are case _expressions_.)

Comment: FYI `case` is an *expression* not a *statement*.

Comment: This might be a rare case to justify a user defined function

Comment: Is the value of "X" significant or is this just a case of null vs. non-null?

Comment: Did you try with COALESCE ()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue here with the example below

```
select 
count(case when c1 = '$' then 1 else null end) 
+ count(case when c2 = '$' then 1 else null end)
+ count(case when c3 = '$' then 1 else null end) 
+ count(case when c4 = '$' then 1 else null end) 
+ count(case when c5 = '$' then 1 else null end) cnt
from your_table
```

Answer (score 1):

One method would be string concatenation and then comparing the results:

```
select t.*,
       (case when len(concat(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h)) like '%X%X%'
             then 'good' else 'bad'
        end) as two_x_flag
from t;
```

The `concat()` function conveniently ignores `NULL` values.

You can also use `apply` with aggregation to count the number of `'X'`s:

```
select t.*,
       (case when v.num_x >= 2 then 1 else 0 end) as two_x_flag
from t cross apply
     (select count(*) as num_x
      from (values (t.a), (t.b), (t.c), (t.d), (t.e), (t.f), (t.g), (t.h)) v(x)
      where v.x = 'X'
     ) v
```

Answer (score 0):

*If* I understand you correctly, you could use `apply()` and `iif` to give you a count of the number of nulls or non-nulls

```
select t.* 
from t
outer apply (
    select Iif(a is null,0,1) + Iif(b is null,0,1) + Iif(c is null,0,1) t
)tot
where tot.t >= 2; /* eg only rows with at least 2 columns with X */
```

Another even simpler option would be to use `concat` which eliminates NULL values

```
select t.* 
from t
outer apply ( select Len(Concat(a,b,c))t )tot
where t >= 2
```